# React with Socket.io - continously re-render on "socket.on" event

Tags: reactjs, flask, websocket, socket.io, react-component

I'm trying to write a client that opens a socket.io connection with a server and then continuously re-renders the screen with an updated number that is sent from the server through the socket. I can't get the number to update. The "speed" value stays at 10. What's the issue? - clearly a very basic error in my understanding. Thanks!

The client code:

```
  import React from 'react';
    import {CircleGauge} from 'react-launch-gauge';
    import io from 'socket.io-client';


    class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context)
            this.state = {
                speed: 10
            };
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
            socket.on( 'data update', data => this.setState({speed: data}));
            console.log("got the speed: " + this.state.speed);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p> The velocity received is: {this.state.speed}  </p>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default App;
```

The server code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import time

sendData = False;

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('connect')
def dataSent():
    print('they connected*************')
    for i in range(20,100):
        emit('data update', i)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug = True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Check my working code below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import socket from 'socket.io-client'

const Chatbox = () => {
  const [chats, setChats] = useState([])
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
  const socketClientRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const client = socket("http://localhost:3002");
    client.on("connect", () => {
      console.log('connected')
    })
    client.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log('diconnected')
    });
    client.on("chat", message => {
      setChats(prevChats => [...prevChats, message])
      // INSTEAD OF:
      // setChats([...chats, message])
    });
    socketClientRef.current = client
    return () => {
      client.removeAllListeners()
    }
  }, [])

  const handleSend = async () => {
    socketClientRef.current.emit('chat', {
      room: `event-${eventId}`,
      message
    })
    setMessage('')
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Messages</h1>
        {chats.map(chat => (
          <div>{chat}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <input value={message} onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={handleSend}>Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but there are a couple minor issues with the way you're setting up your socket on the client.

First, you were setting up the socket a little differently than the docs suggest.

```
componentDidMount() {
  // io() not io.connect()
  this.socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

  this.socket.on(
    // consider renaming this to 'data_update' or just 'update'
    'data update', 
    data => 
      this.setState(
        { speed: data },
        // the second parameter to setState will be called on completion, so you'll log every time the speed changes
        () => console.log("got the speed: " + this.state.speed)
      )
  );

  this.socket.open();
}
```

Finally, you'll want to close the socket when your component unmounts:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.socket.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Luke, but it didn't solve the issue. For some reason, the console shows no output (and the velocity doesn't change) until the server sends the final value of 99. At this point, all 80 logs are printed and the velocity is updated to 99